# Decrypt gpg in Java without using Java.Runtime

Tags: java, rsa, gnupg

I have a .gpg file and a RSA private key. How can I programatically decrypt it without using operating system? e.g. without using something like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gpg -decrypt.....");`

Libraries I've found all run operating system. Like [GnuPG](http://www.macnews.co.il/mageworks/java/gnupg/GnuPG.java) or [gnugpg-for-java](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/libraries.en.html).

Comment: tried [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html)?

Comment: [Bouncy Castle](http://www.docjar.org/html/api/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/ByteArrayHandler.java.html) requires a passphrase not a secret key,

Comment: @MortezaShahriariNia: BouncyCastle supports all the encryption methods that GPG does.

Answer (score 3):

As Skyr mentioned: Bouncy Castle is the way to go.

What do you want to do with this key? If your goal is to en- or decrypt files you might want to take a look at [bouncy-gpg](https://github.com/neuhalje/bouncy-gpg)  (shameless plug: I wrote it).

Using secret keys is actually three steps

1. Parse the key and put it into a `PGPSecretKeyRing`
2. Extract the secret key from the keyring
3. Decrypt it with the password

#### 1. Parsing the exported key

In any case look here for [the part that parses keys](https://github.com/neuhalje/bouncy-gpg/blob/master/src/main/java/name/neuhalfen/projects/crypto/bouncycastle/openpgp/keys/keyrings/InMemoryKeyring.java):

```
class ...

private PGPSecretKeyRingCollection secretKeyRings = new PGPSecretKeyRingCollection(EMPTY_LIST);

 ...

/**
 * Add a new secret keyring to the public keyrings.
 * .
 * Can read the result of "gpg --export" and "gpg --export -a keyid"
 * .
 * E.g. "gpg --export-secret-key -a keyid":
 * addSecretKey("-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK----- ....".getBytes("US-ASCII")
 * <p>
 * The password is queried via the callback (decryptionSecretKeyPassphraseForSecretKeyId).
 *
 * @param encodedPrivateKey the key ascii armored or binary
 * @throws IOException  IO is dangerous
 * @throws PGPException E.g. this is nor a valid key
 */
public void addSecretKey(byte[] encodedPrivateKey) throws IOException, PGPException {

    if (encodedPrivateKey == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("encodedPrivateKey must not be null");
    }

    try (
            final InputStream raw = new ByteArrayInputStream(encodedPrivateKey);
            final InputStream decoded = org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(raw)
    ) {
        PGPSecretKeyRing pgpPrivate = new PGPSecretKeyRing(decoded, getKeyFingerPrintCalculator());
        this.secretKeyRings = PGPSecretKeyRingCollection.addSecretKeyRing(this.secretKeyRings, pgpPrivate);
    }
}
```

---

#### 2. Getting the key from the keyring

```
       final PGPSecretKeyRingCollection pgpSec = ...
       final PGPSecretKey encryptedKey = pgpSec.getSecretKey(keyID);
```

---

#### 3. Decrypting the key

Later you have to [decrypt the key using a password like so](https://github.com/neuhalje/bouncy-gpg/blob/master/src/main/java/name/neuhalfen/projects/crypto/bouncycastle/openpgp/keys/PGPUtilities.java):

```
 /**
 * Decrypt an encrypted PGP secret key.
 *
 * @param encryptedKey An encrypted key
 * @param passphrase   The passphrase for the key
 * @return the decrypted secret key
 * @throws PGPException E.g. wrong passphrase
 */
public static PGPPrivateKey extractPrivateKey(PGPSecretKey encryptedKey, final char[] passphrase) throws PGPException {
    LOGGER.debug("Extracting secret key with key ID '0x{}'", Long.toHexString(encryptedKey.getKeyID()));

    PGPDigestCalculatorProvider calcProvider = new JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder()
            .setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME).build();

    PBESecretKeyDecryptor decryptor = new JcePBESecretKeyDecryptorBuilder(
            calcProvider).setProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME)
            .build(passphrase);

    return encryptedKey.extractPrivateKey(decryptor);
}
```

Comment: can't you add your maven jar at a common public maven repository? I don't want to add additional repository.

Comment: The last time I looked it was a real hassle to add something to maven central. Since jcenter is a superset of maven central that was the easiest way to get a wide distribution. But any PR is welcome!

Comment: Yeah, there are some requirements in order to put it on Maven Repo.  But thanks for the library.  Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) library provides (among other features) an OpenPGP implementation. The package `org.bouncycastle.openpgp.examples` contains several usage examples, one of them showing how to encrypt/decrypt a file using a public/secret key pair (you can have a look at the examples on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.bouncycastle/bcpg-jdk16/1.46/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/KeyBasedFileProcessor.java) or on the [project's Github mirror](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/KeyBasedFileProcessor.java)).

Comment: See https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/tree/master/pg/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples

Comment: Are OpenPGP and GnuPG compatible? 

Edit: > GnuPG is a complete and free implementation of the OpenPGP standard as defined by RFC4880 (also known as PGP).

Answer (score 1):

there are too many examples that I've tried on Bouncy Castle with PGP.  The common issue is keyID can't be found in KeyRing.

So, I found @Jens' bouncy-gpg (not sure if he still maintains it.)

Here is his documentation from github.io.  It's simple to follow and works!
https://neuhalje.github.io/bouncy-gpg/